# TypeScript. FormGroup FormArray - remove only one element object by value. Angular 2 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    images: this.fb.array([])
});
```

I add new element in this way:
`this.images.push(new FormControl(new ImageCreateForm(this.imageResponse.id)));`

```
get images(): FormArray {
    return <FormArray>this.formGroup.controls.images;
}
```

My classes:

```
export class ImageCreateForm {
    id: number;
    constructor(id: number) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

export class ImageResponse {
    id: number;
    url: string;
}
```

When I added images, then my `{{ formGroup.value | json }}` is:

```
"images": [
   {
    "id": 501
   },
   {
    "id": 502
   },
   {
    "id": 503
   }
]
```

I want to remove images (for example only image with `id=502`) from `formGroup` before when I send my form POST request. Is it possible?
I tried use `reset` method, but this remove all elements:
`this.images.reset({"id":image.id});`. Where `image` it is a `ImageResponse` object.

Result: `{"images": [ null, null, null ]}`, but I want:

```
"images": [
   {
    "id": 501
   },
   {
    "id": 503
   }
]
```

Answer (score 235, accepted):

`FormArray` class has [`removeAt`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#removeAt) which takes the index. If you do not know the index, you can do a workaround:

```
// findIndex returns -1 if not found
// `removeAt` wraps around from the back if given negative
const index = this.images.value.findIndex(image => image.id === 502)
if(index !== -1) this.images.removeAt(index)
```

Comment: This is the correct way to remove from a FormArray. *Don't* use *formArray*.controls[i].splice - that will remove the control from the array but the control *values* will remain on the `values` array of the `FormArray` control.

Answer (score 22):

In Angular Reactive Forms, `formArray` has a method called `removeAt()`.
You can use it by passing an index that you want to delete:

```
delete(index){
    this.array.removeAt(index)
}
``
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two different cases where you may don't want to send value for a formcontrol.

1. In case you have a value for that and want to remove before post

   ```
   this.form.removeControl('controlname');
   ```
2. If you model validation is failing after posting but you still want that control in your form. In this case you can only initialize this field value as undefined. This way it will not post along with formdata values.

   ```
   this.formBuilder.group({    
      name: ['', [Validators.required],
      imageUrl: [undefined, []],
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove a value for a particular Key from the FormGroup, You can use following code -

```
this.formGroupF.controls[value].patchValue(null)
```

Comment: That way you are setting null for the value field of the form. But if you really want to remove an element completely, you can do it this way.

    this.form.removeControl('value');

I often use this for unit tests that have lines like these

    this.form.get('value')?.value